# ¿Como puedo mandar a imprimir en una clase, varias variables que ingreso y tengo en otra clase?

Tags: java

El programa es para una renta de bicicletas, yo ingreso el tiempo que desee el cliente y su nombre para autorizar la renta, y en la otra clase mando a imprimir las variables del tiempo, el nombre del cliente y el total del importe de la renta
La clase principal es esta:

```
package bicicletas;

public class Bicicletas {

    public static void main (String[] args ) {

        System.out.println("Bienvenido a rentas Bayka");

        Renta R = new Renta();
        R.Datos();
    }

    public static void despliegue () {

        Renta instancia1 = new Renta();
        Renta instancia2 = new Renta();
        Renta instancia3 = new Renta();



    System.out.println("El tiempo de renta es: "+instancia1.tiempo);
    System.out.println("Su nombre es: "+instancia2.nombre);
    System.out.println("El precio de la renta es: "+instancia3.total);
    System.out.println("Gracias por su renta :) ");
    }
}
```

La segunda clase es esta:

```
package bicicletas;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Renta {

        int total;
        int tiempo;
        String nombre;

    public static void Datos() {

        int precio=30;

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese el tiempo que le gustaria rentar (en horas): ");
        tiempo = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre: ");
        nombre = teclado.next();

        total = tiempo * precio;

        Bicicletas D = new Bicicletas();
        D.despliegue();
    }

}
```

Comment: Necesitas darle formato al código de tu pregunta, y contarnos que problemas tienes con tu solución, no solo copiar y pegar y esperar que alguien resuelva el algoritmo, más información en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

Hagamos un analisis rapido de tu codigo.

Arranca por el main.
Ahi defines una clase Renta. y llamas a su metodo Datos. Y ahi es cuando me doy cuenta que no sabes que es programar con clases.

Estas usando la clase como si fuera un procedimiento, sin entender el concepto de clases.

Tu clase renta, luego de hacer lo que tiene que hacer, vuelve a llamar a la clase bicicleta (que es donde esta el main), y llama a la función despliegue.

(Nota aparte: hay un mal uso de funciones estáticas por todos lados, deberías leer respecto a eso también).

La función despliegue genera 3 clases vacías de renta, y luego trata de imprimir un dato de cada una de las 3 clases distintas que no existen. No se como era el ejercicio original de tu tarea, y si estas estudiando clases o programación estructurada, pero habría que hacer todo tu código de vuelta y no tiene mucho sentido que te lo escribamos nosotros.

Como nota al margen, para imprimir el valor de una variable en una clase, lo que haces esta bien.

```
Renta instancia1 = new Renta();
System.out.println("El tiempo de renta es: "+instancia1.tiempo);
```

Salvo que la clase que contiene instancia1, esta vacía, y no va a imprimir nada.

Tienes un concepto erróneo sobre ámbito de variables (scope en ingles, el ciclo de vida de las mismas).

Para que tu caso funcionara, deberia ser algo asi:

```
Renta instancia1 = new Renta();
instancia1.Datos();
System.out.println("El tiempo de renta es: "+instancia1.tiempo);
```